# getting control id of sharepoint inputformtextbox in javascript?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, controls, richtextbox

How to getting control id (editor control of the sharepoint inputformtextbox) of sharepoint inputformtextbox in javascript?. I had integrated one page containg this controls to moss 2010 page. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var ddlObjects = document.getElementById('<%= ddlObjects.ClientID %>');
```